# Trying to build a simple java program in intellij shows "Java(TM) Platform SE binary has stopped working"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

so I have java se installed (version jdk1.8.0 144) and intellij 2.4,

I did everything correctly like I found [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-running-and-packaging-your-first-java-application.html)

and I tried uninstalling and reinstalling (both java and intellij)

I first time tried a few months ago (intellij was still 2.2 if I remember correctly) and had this problem I decided to try again today but still the same problem,

here is a gif of the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9Y7K.jpg)

sorry if the problem is stupid but I couldn't find a solution anywhere searched google for hours,

oh btw if it matters I have eclipse installed and I didn't face problems with it

Comment: Try with 32-bit JDK instead of 64-bit one. Does it crash in the same way? Any security tools/antiviruses running? Does it help if you disable them?

Comment: @CrazyCoder my windows 7 is 64 bit, should I try installing a 32 bit jdk anyway? and I tried disabling my antivirus and it didn't change anything

Comment: Yes, you can try using 32-bit JDK.

Comment: @CrazyCoder should I uninstall the 64 bit jdk first?

Comment: No, you can have both installed.

Comment: Never mind I solved the problem by updating my nvidia driver which I decided to try after I read [this](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/java_crash_video_driver.xml) multiple times when I searched google for the problem but I never believed a graphics driver could affect it (it still makes no sense to me) but it's fixed now, thank you very much

Comment: Yes, it's a known issue with the specific NVidia driver version. I didn't think about it since it was resolved long time ago and most people have already updated. Sorry.